# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bulkDelete' of undefined when making bang parameters

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm able to clear text fine but my message has been cleared embed doesn't send when the argument is only one and all of my error messages leave errors in logs. I was able to send messages fine and I only got errors when I converted everything to embeds so I'm guessing the issue has to be with embeds.

```
module.exports = {
    name: "clear",
    description: "clear messages",
    async execute(message, args, Discord) {
        if (message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_MESSAGES"])) {
            if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) { 
                    let botPerms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .addField("Error:",'I don\'t have the required permission to clear messages')
                    .setColor("#000000")
                    message.channel.send(
                        botPerms
                ).then(msg => {
                    msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                  })
                  .catch;
            }
            if (!args[0]) {
                    let blankcommand = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`Command: !o clear`)
                    .addField('Example:', '!o clear 5')
                    .setColor("#000000")
                    message.channel.send(
                        blankcommand
                )
                  .catch;}
            else if (isNaN(args[0])) {
                let invalidNumber = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .addField("Error:","You must provide a valid number of messages you wish to clear.")
                .setColor("#000000")
                message.channel.send(
                    invalidNumber
                ).then(msg => {
                    msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                  })
                  .catch; }
            else if (args[0] > 100) {
                let over100 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .addField("Error:","You can\'t clear over 100 messages.")
                .setColor("#000000")
                message.channel.send(
                    over100
                ).then(msg => {
                    msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                  })
                  .catch;}
            else if (args[0] < 1) {
                let noMessages = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .addField("Error:","You must clear at least one message.")
                .setColor("#000000")
                message.channel.send(
                    noMessages
                ).then(msg => {
                    msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                  })
                  .catch;}

            await message.channel.messages
                .fetch({ limit: parseInt(args[0]) + 1 })
                .then((messages) => {
                    message.channel
                        .bulkDelete(parseInt(args[0]) + 1)
                        .then(() => {
                            if (args[0] > 1) { 
                                let clearMessages = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .addField("Success:",`Cleared ${args[0]} messages.`)
                            .setColor("#000000")
                            message.channel.send(
                                clearMessages
                            ).then(msg => {
                                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                              })
                              .catch
                            
                            } if (args[0] === 1) {
                                let oneMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .addField("Success:",`Cleared ${args[0]} message.`)
                            .setColor("#000000")
                            message.channel.send(
                                oneMessage
                            ).then(msg => {
                                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                              })
                              .catch
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((err) => { 
                            let errorMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .addField("Error:",`Unable to clear messages older than 14 days.`)
                            .setColor("#000000")
                            message.channel.send(
                                errorMessage
                            ).then(msg => {
                                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
                              })
                        });
                });
        } else {
            let noPerms = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                            .addField("Error:",`You do not have the permission to do that.`)
                            .setColor("#000000")
                            message.channel.send(
                                noPerms
                            )
            .then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
              })
              .catch;
        }
    },
};
```

Log error:

```
2021-07-31T17:42:40.255291+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bulkDelete' of undefined
2021-07-31T17:42:40.255352+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at /app/commands/clear.js:63:26
2021-07-31T17:42:40.255353+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
2021-07-31T17:42:40.255354+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at async Object.execute (/app/commands/clear.js:59:13)
2021-07-31T17:42:40.255354+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-07-31T17:42:40.255390+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2021-07-31T17:42:40.259844+00:00 app[Worker.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: The title and the error message at the end of your post don't match.

Comment: Where is the error coming from exactly? Please convert your code into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are continuing to execute the command even if the user supplied wrong arguments or even no arguments. Just wrap the `await message.channel.messages ...`  inside of `else { await message.channel.messages ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are continuing to execute the command even if the user supplied wrong arguments or even no arguments. Just wrap the `await message.channel.messages ...`  inside of `else { await message.channel.messages ... }`.

Also check if the argument is greater than or equal to 100, because later you are adding 1 to that argument.

```js
if (!args[0]) {
    // handle no arguments
}
else if (isNaN(args[0])) {
    // handle argument is not a number
}
else if (args[0] >= 100) {
    // handle argument is greater than or equal to 100
}
else if (args[0] < 1) {
    // handle argument is lesser than 1
}
else {
    await message.channel.messages
        .fetch({ limit: parseInt(args[0]) + 1 })
        .then((messages) => {
            // rest of your code
        });
}
```